# Почему цикл вывода на PHP картинок из БД выводит только первые пять изображений и не больше?

Tags: php, база-данных, изображения, циклы

уважаемые эксперты! Проблема в следующем: цикл foreach выводит почему-то только первые пять бинарных BLOB-картинок из БД PHPmyadmin. Вот код:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pl ORDER BY id";
$sth = $connection->query($sql);
foreach ($sth as $result) {
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['img'] ).'"/>';
}
```

До этого все работает хорошо. Подозревал, что дело в конфигурационных файлах Денвера: php.ini или config.inc.php (конфигурационные файлы phpmyadmin).. везде поднял ограничения, так что дело не в этом. Заменял id у разных фотографий, и любая фотка, оказывающаяся в первых пяти отображается..

Comment: width="50" height="50" добавь

Comment: Спасибо! То есть, стоит попробовать обернуть img дивами? и задать свойства классу?

Answer (score 1):

Так, может:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pl ORDER BY id";
$sth = $connection->query($sql);
while ($result=$sth->fetch_array()) {
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['img'] ).'"/>';
}
```

Comment: Попробовал так, дает следующую ошибку: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchArray() in Z:\home\localhost\www\fullsizeimages.php on line 40 Может, потому что у меня php 5..

Comment: Сорри ->fetch_array (исправил в ответе)

Comment: Ого! Все работает, спасибо Вам огромное! Правда, я не понял, в чем была ошибка..

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!